# Keynote no longer free on my OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, keynote, iwork

I received **"You have iWork apps for OS X Mavericks available."** notification and went to install the suite from the App Store. Keynote was stuck on waiting, so I clicked the 'x' icon and now it has disappeared from the purchased tab. In launcher it's still showing up as "waiting", and in the App Store it's now a $19.99 purchase instead of free.